# Is positive definite function (dynamical systems) always convex?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, be such that

1. $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$,
2. $f(0) = 0$,
3. $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus\{0\}$.

Is it true that such function must be convex on a neighborhood of the origin? If not, can you come up with a counterexample?

Considering the simplest scenario when $n = 1$, I expect that a smooth function with infinite amount of minima approaching the origin should serve as a counterexample. But I am unable to construct an explicit formula for the function.

Comment: if it is smooth (or even $C^2$), then it is surely convex , since its second derivative is positive

Comment: @Exodd Interesting! Could you show me a sketch of the proof for a $C^2$ function? Or is this available in the literature?

Comment: for $C^2$ functions, just expand $f(h) + f(-h) -2f(0) / h^2$ with Taylor, to find that $f''(0)\ge 0$

Comment: @Exodd It seems like $f(x) = x^6(1 + \sin^2(x^{-1}))$ disproves your claim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in general no. As a general counterexample, consider any smooth strictly positive function $f_0$ that is defined on the unit sphere $S^{n-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and then define $f$ to be homogeneous of degree $p>1$ such that $f$ agrees with $f_0$ on $S^{n-1}$, that is
$$
f(x) = \|x\|^p f_0(x/\|x\|)
$$
for $x \ne 0$. Then $f$ is clearly $C^1$, but it need not be convex in any neighborhood of the origin.

For a one-dimensional counterexample, consider $f(x) = x^4 \left( 1 + \sin^2(x^{-1}) \right)$.

Comment: I have troubles understanding the general counterexample. If I take $n = 2$, $\|\cdot\|$ as the Euclidean norm, $p = 2$, and I set $f_0 \equiv 1$ on the unit sphere $S^1$, then $f(x) = x^2 + y^2$ which is clearly convex. Am I missing something?

Comment: @sleepingrabbit, his general counterexample is a counterexample in the sense that a function with that form will satisfy your hypothesis without *necessarily* being convex about the origin, he is not saying that any function of that form is not convex about the origin. You can think of it rather as a guide to find concrete counterexamples.

Comment: @Hal Okay, in that case I don't fully understand what use is this general "counterexample". But I'm happy with the one-dimensional counterexample.